# Consider particle interactions in the string, why are tensions in the pulley different when the pulley has a mass or moment of inertia?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

From answers to the following question
[Why are tensions in the pulley different when the pulley has a mass or moment of inertia?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/197048/why-are-tensions-in-the-pulley-different-when-the-pulley-has-a-mass-or-moment-of), I understand that the reason for that is because the difference in tension is the driving force behind the angular acceleration of the pulley.

However, I don't find this explanation completely satisfying - why does the pulley *has to* be set into rotation in the process in the first place?

Thus, I am wondering if there is an explanation for why tensions in the pulley are different when the pulley has a mass or moment of inertia **considering the interactions between the particles in the string**?

I think this may be a better way to address the causality of the process the pulley system undergoes as it proceeds in the following direction:

1. due to [answer to the above question], there has to be a difference in the tensions
2. due to the difference in the tensions, the pulley gains an angular acceleration during the process

A picture showing the pulley system that I was talking about:
[image]

Comment: The premise isn't correct; the tensions are *not* necessarily different if the pulley is massive. However, if they *are* different and there's no axle friction, then the pulley will accelerate according to the rotational version of Newton's Second Law. It's unclear what your question is.

Comment: what do you mean by your answer "considering the interactions between the particles in the string?"

Answer (score 2):

In real situations a pulley will have mass and frictions. So string tension will have to become higher on one side of the pulley than the other side to provide a net torque high enough to overcome frictions and start rotating the mass of the pulley.

Comment: Thank you! When you are referring to friction, is it the friction between the string and the pulley or pulley and its bearing?

Comment: There are both in real situations, the rope to pulley friction allows force to be applied to the pulley. The axle friction, though it may be small, must be overcome for the pulley to turn.

Answer (score 0):

The pulley has to be set in rotation when the masses are moving.

That type of pulley helps the string provide a frictionless link between the masses, by rotating so that the string doesn't need to slip over it.

Other explanations aren't really needed, if the pulley has mass the difference in tension provides the torque needed to make it rotate.

Comment: So if the mass on the platform is zero the tension arises solely from the pulley reacting to the force that sets it in motion? Say, rotational inertia?  Im very interedted in your cosmological view. But thats another point.

Comment: @Vielloosoof yes, in that case the other mass would almost be in free fall, but there would be some tension in the vertical part of the string (that would rotate the pulley), but no tension in the horizontal part of the string.